# Reading headers from a csv file using DictReader and without fieldnames() method

Tags: python, csv

I have the following (toy) data in a csv file named 'my_file.csv':

```
Person  City          State  Age
John    Los Angeles   CA     34 
Mary    Boston        MA     27 
Phil    London        N/A    30
```

I'd like to be able to print a list of the headers.  I'm using the following to create a `reader` object, then printing the `fieldnames`:

```
import csv
filepath = my_file.csv"
col_names = [] 

with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    print(reader.fieldnames)
```

Is it possible to print the field names **without** using the fieldnames() method?  (e.g. iterating over `reader` in some way)

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is correct as is, although the first line is not needed.  Are you sure your .CSV file is properly formatted?  First line is the headers, separated by commas?  No extra blank lines at the top?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
col_names = []

import csv
with open('my_file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    for field in reader.fieldnames:
        col_names.append(field)

print(col_names)

[Person, City, State, Age]
```

Comment: This is adding nothing to the OP's code.  `reader.fieldnames` is already a list.  No need to build another one.

Comment: @MarkTolonen -- is there a way to get the column headers without using the `fieldnames` method?

Comment: Use `reader` instead of `DictReader` and read the first row.